# Spring application doesn't respond

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I have Spring MVC application with connection to MySQL database. It runs on Tomcat server. I have a problem that the application doesn't respond after a few requests.

Case:
I restart Tomcat server and open a page in a browser. The application runs and the server returns generated page to a browser. But when I open 5th-6th page in a browser, the server doesn't respond. Browser is still loading without no respond.

Here is the connector from tomcat configuration *server.xml*

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" keystoreFile="C:\Users\misco\.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" maxThreads="200" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

I tried to monitor the tomcat using `jvisualvm` tool.

I also looked on MySQL server status. There are threads with sleep status.

Here is part of thread dump from `jvisualvm`.

```
2013-07-19 09:31:17
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.3-b01 mixed mode):
"http-nio-8443-exec-25" daemon prio=6 tid=0x27b84000 nid=0x1b64 waiting on condition [0x299ff000]



"http-nio-8443-exec-18" daemon prio=6 tid=0x27b81400 nid=0x1768 in Object.wait() [0x2972d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:793)
    - locked <0x0c2e99b0> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:115)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:430)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1596)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:717)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1933)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3270)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1080)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:997)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:990)
    at com.myapp.cloud.dao.store.CategoryDAOImpl.get(CategoryDAOImpl.java:40)
    at com.myapp.cloud.service.store.CategoryServiceImpl.get(CategoryServiceImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy68.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.myapp.cloud.controller.ProductController.detail(ProductController.java:227)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    - locked <0x10af42b8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x108ba180> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"http-nio-8443-exec-12" daemon prio=6 tid=0x262d6000 nid=0x4024 in Object.wait() [0x2932d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:793)
    - locked <0x0fd5b3f8> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:115)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:430)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1596)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:717)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1933)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3270)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1080)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:997)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:990)
    at com.myapp.cloud.dao.store.ProductDAOImpl.get(ProductDAOImpl.java:47)
    at com.myapp.cloud.service.store.ProductServiceImpl.get(ProductServiceImpl.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy210.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.myapp.cloud.controller.ProductController.edit(ProductController.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    - locked <0x10af4358> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x108b9be8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"http-nio-8443-exec-10" daemon prio=6 tid=0x262d5400 nid=0x5dc in Object.wait() [0x291be000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:793)
    - locked <0x0c2e99b0> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:115)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:430)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:334)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy67.getByPage(Unknown Source)
    at com.myapp.cloud.controller.ProductController.loadPage(ProductController.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    - locked <0x10af4738> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x108b9928> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x103c4b58> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-8443-exec-24" daemon prio=6 tid=0x27b83800 nid=0x2cfc waiting on condition [0x29aff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x103c4b58> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-8443-exec-23" daemon prio=6 tid=0x27b83000 nid=0x3414 waiting on condition [0x299af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x103c4b58> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-8443-exec-22" daemon prio=6 tid=0x27b82c00 nid=0x35f0 waiting on condition [0x2990f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x103c4b58> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-8443-exec-21" daemon prio=6 tid=0x27b82400 nid=0x1d48 waiting on condition [0x2922f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x103c4b58> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-8443-exec-20" daemon prio=6 tid=0x27b82000 nid=0x1688 waiting on condition [0x2979f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x103c4b58> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Can you give me an advice how to fix this issue?

**Edit 1:**

Here are spring beans related to db connection

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Database connection isn't closed.

Comment: It looks like threads are waiting for a connection from DBCP. You probably forgot to close JDBC connections in a finally block.

Comment: connectionTimeout="20000" try increasing this value

Comment: @JBNizet I use hibernate for connection management, so I don't use any finally block.

Comment: @SanjayaLiyanage Originally I use connector without this value (with default 60000), it was added after the issue occurence

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you may not be closing the Hibernate Sessions in `com.myapp.cloud.dao.store.ProductDAOImpl.get(ProductDAOImpl.java`.  Connections from the pool are all used by first 5 request, and subsequent request are waiting for new connection from the database connection pool.